# Steam says not enough space even though files are already on my hard drive

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

I have got gta v on A USB from a friend, I have put in the steams apps, common folder, but when I click install on steam it says not enough disc space. I have a 118 gb computer and I can only just fit it in but it does fit with 2 gb left. Is there a way to let steam recon use that it is on my computer?

Comment: Seems like the game is still packed. The game needs an additional ~60 GB to install, because it first needs to unpack itself.

Comment: ... 118 GB isn't enough? Dear gods, what *is* this game?

Comment: That said, I suspect @5pike has it right.

Comment: Found something on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/32i328/gta_5for_those_that_the_unpacking_uses_all_the/) that might help. If you try this and it works, make sure to post it as an answer.

Comment: Basically to install the game that way you need double the amount of free space. You need 65GB for the files you copied over and 65GB free so that the Steam client thinks it has enough space to download and install the files, even though it doesn't need to. See my answer to this question for another way of doing this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/214120/how-to-get-steam-to-recognize-game-files-downloaded-on-another-machine

Answer (score 1):

There isn't enough space, it is correct. The initial installation is 118GB, but after DLC, multiplayer caches, saves, etc. etc. the 2GB left over won't be enough. Clear enough 5GB or so off your HDD before you install the game.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy gta to another drive, start installing it on steam. Wait till the first bytes are done. Close steam, copy the data back, start steam and you should be happy. The download resumes, load the last bytes and should be done.

This normally works for me.

Btw. This way you will see how much space is needed AFTER installation, due to the fact that you start the installation normally.